# Can XCode deploy to iOS devices when there is no internet connection?

Tags: ios, xcode

To my chagrin, when trying to deploy to iOS XCode refused to install my app because there was no internet connection present to verify my developer account. I've installed to this particular iOS device before, the only difference was that I was on the move and without internet.

[image]

Beyond Apple's signing policies being generally developer-hostile, in my case it is actively hostile to my efforts since I want to go into the field-- in this case tens of miles offshore-- and do some rapid device development iteration.

I do not have the paid developer account, and that is perhaps a limitation. Happy to get a paid account if it will resolve this blockage.